# Boost threads terminates program?

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, boost

I have a boost thread program from a tutorial, i can compile it with no problems or warnings but when i run it i don't get any output form eclipse. The program termiates a once. I'm using MiNGW with my eclipse could this be the problem?

Does anybody have a idea? All sugestions are welcome!

Below is the tutorial code that i used, its from [this site](http://antonym.org/2009/05/threading-with-boost---part-i-creating-threads.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

void workerFunc()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(10000);

    std::cout << "Worker: running" << std::endl;

    // Pretend to do something useful...
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);

    std::cout << "Worker: finished" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "main: startup" << std::endl;

    boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);

    std::cout << "main: waiting for thread" << std::endl;

    workerThread.join();

    std::cout << "main: done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Update

I have linked pthreads under mingw linker and the program compiles but the result is the same. When i put i breakpoiiny just below main i get this:

The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
[New Thread 4168.0xbf8]

And the program terminates does anybody have idea?

Comment: Did you try to build executable and run it without eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Don't forget, you can have multiple breakpoints in multiple threads in Eclipse, so you can see what your main does step by step, as well as your worker thread.

Comment: Works fine in visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're linking in both the boost_thread and pthread libraries.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! Can someone tell me how to link -pthread with mingw(and eclipse). Does mingw have pthread?

Comment: right-click on your project, select "Properties".  When that window opens up, select "C/C++ Build->Settings".  Under GCC C++ Linker, select "LIbraries", and then add the libraries you need.

Comment: I have linked ptheds in eclipse with mingw linker but the result is the same. Does anybody have a idea?

Comment: Thanks! for the reply i have linked pthreads i thinks under mingw linker, the program compiles but the result is the same. I have updated my post with a breakpoint output form the debug. Doe you have a idea?